# Windows 7 machine rebooting during Backup & Restore

Tags: windows-7, backup, reboot

Over the last year my computer has been randomly(?) rebooting; I did a clean install of Windows 7 twice, checked temperatures, hard-drive diagnostics, did CPU stress tests & swapped out all the components except for the motherboard & harddrive to no avail. I had not experienced the issue for the last 2 months and forgot about it...

But then just today it happened again & found out how to reproduce this reboot on purpose during normal use.

I was setting up a first backup through the Backup & Restore menu and when I got to the last step in the wizard and clicked on "Backup now", the machine restarted itself.

When I go back into the Backup & Restore menu:
[image: Menu]
and click on "Manage Space" the machine reboots. I've done this 4 times now and it reboots every time. (Note this is the first time I set up this Backup scheduler, and it's off again now) I have looked through the Event viewer for anything suspicious but I didn't find anything.

What could be causing this? What actually happens during the Manage Backup and Backup now processes? Is there a way to turn on more verbose logging?

*EDIT: I also turned off "Automatically Restart" in Startup & Recovery settings, issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest doing a full hardware diagnostic on the system.  This could be one of too many things, memory, heat, power supply would be first on my hit parade.  Next would be disk or disk controller.

Isn't there are hardware testing function on the Windows rescue disk?  Or is that type of full diag provided only on the DELL systems.

Comment: I know Dell systems have those, but I don't think I have it available to me. Can you recommend me a comprehensive hardware diagnostic tool?